# Python Selenium - How to click on a javascript button

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to Python and Selenium. I have the following code for a button on my site and I am unable to click on it using

```
 driver.find_element_by_id("AddToBasket").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='AddToCartButton']").click()
```

Hovering over the button just displays `javascript:void(0)`

So here is my Code

```
<div class="add">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="AddToBasket" class="addtobtn addtobag">
      <span>Add to cart</span>
    </a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# You need a mouse to hover the span elements here
self.mouse = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver)    

# You need get the span element from its xpath:
value = 'Add to cart'
span_xpath = '//span[contains(text(), "' + value + '")]'
span_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(span_xpath)

# Then you hover on span element by mouse and click on it:
self.mouse.move_to_element(span_element).click().perform()
```